# Análisis de Algoritmo

Tags: c, bucles, algoritmos, sum

en mi clase de Análisis de algoritmos nos han dado el siguiente código

```
sum = 0;
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<i; j++)
        sum++;
```

Nos dicen de calcular las veces que se ejecuta la OB(que es sum++), nos han dado la respuesta y resulta que es (n(n + 1))/2, ¿cómo se llega a esta conclusión?

Comment: El bucle exterior se ejecuta N veces. Por cada iteración del bucle exterior, el bucle interior se ejecuta i veces. Por tanto la operación se ejecuta 1+2+3+4+...+N veces. Esa suma se calcula como la suma de los términos de una progresión aritmética de paso 1, y de ahi sale N(N+1)/2

Answer (score 0):

Esto parece más una pregunta matemática que de programación.

Puedes escribir ambos ciclos de la siguiente manera:

[image: Ecuación]

Nota que sumar **i** veces el mismo número es la manera en que aprendemos la multiplicación.

[image: Ecuación]

Entonces:

[image: Ecuación]

Esto último es una [serie aritmética](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progresi%C3%B3n_aritm%C3%A9tica#Suma). Se demostró que:

[image: Ecuación]

O en español, que la suma de **n** elementos de una progresión aritmética es igual a la suma del primer y el último elemento, multiplicada por la la **n** (la cantidad de elementos) dividido por 2.

Entonces, como el primer elemento es **1** y el último **n**:

[image: Ecuación]